# Discrepancy in Father's Name | UK Tier-2 visa

Tags: uk, working-visas

I have been recently hired by a company based in the UK as a software engineer. As my official role is based in the UK, the HR department has asked me to start the visa process.

Before starting the visa process, I was reviewing my documents and noticed a spelling mistake in my fathers' name, and need clarification if this can be a problem.

- On all of my official documents (mark sheets, degrees, ID card, passport etc), my name is **Muhammad Bilal Wasim**, whilst my fathers' name is **Shahid Wasim**.
- In my fathers' official documents, his official name is **Shahid Waseem**.

For now, I'm planning to move individually to the UK but I may, at some point, want my parents to pay me a visit. Therefore, I need clarification if this will become a hurdle in obtaining my or my parents' visa in the future. If so, is there a way around it other than getting my / my fathers' name fixed across all my documents?

I have contacted various UK visa advisors - Some say this won't be a problem whilst others have suggested to create an **affidavit** and present it to the UK authorities whenever required. Not sure what's the best possible approach.

Comment: So you've contacted professional advisors in the UK, but not satisfied with that you've turned to a bunch of strangers on the Internet who may or may not know what they're doing. What result do you expect?

Comment: Well, I contacted advisors in Pakistan and the wide variety of responses led me to stack exchange. You never know where one may get useful info.

Comment: @Bilal Wasim What is your father’s name on your birth certificate?

Comment: @Traveller, My birth certificate is in my Native language (Urdu). So that won't help I'm afraid.

Comment: Looks like just a difference of transliteration. AFAIK nobody cares about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most people know that transliterations may be different, and that *Waseem* and *Wasim* are two ways of spelling the same name.  In particular, different systems of transliteration fall in and out of favor, which may account for the different spelling on your father's documents.

You may not be able to get the spelling changed on your documents since the transliteration system may be official.  In any event, I suspect that it would be far more trouble than it's worth.

If your parents want to visit you, they will prove their relationship to you, if necessary, with your birth certificate, accompanied by a certified translation.  They will include in their visa application an explanation of the reason for the different spelling.  It surely won't be the first time this has happened, and it will not have an adverse effect on the application.

Answer (score 2):

If you're considering asking a professional expert, you should ask a solicitor **in the UK**. We're just a bunch of people on the net.

Anyone anywhere can call themselves a "UK immigration advisor" but this is a title without licensing or qualifications. A good place to find a qualified solicitor is [ilpa.org.uk](http://ilpa.org.uk)